# What is MM_callJS?

Tags: javascript, eval, code-injection

While checking code for the use of the dreaded `eval` function I found this:

```
function MM_callJS(jsStr) {
    return eval(jsStr)
}
...
<body onLoad="MM_callJS">
```

which seems to me (with my limited Javascript experience) to be utterly pointless because how can `jsStr` ever have it's value set?

Searching online doesn't seem to reveal much other than suggesting to me that MM_callJS might be a convention.

What worries me here is the possibility of an attacker abusing this to execute malicious code if there is some 'magic' way of setting the jsStr parameter.

Comment: According to the code it seems a "longcut" to eval ))

Comment: Oybek is right.  This is just a wrapper around the eval function.  You should search through your code for anywhere that it is calling the "MM_callJS" function because it will eval whatever is passed in to it.

Comment: The only place it is used is shown in the code snippet I've provided.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong in the assumption that the `jsStr` parameter will never be assigned a value. The event handlers are always called with an `event` parameter, describing the event that just happened. It contains fields like `bubbles`, `srcElement` and methods like `preventDefault()`.

So, this object is passed to `eval` for evaluation.

According to MDN ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval ), if `eval` is passed a non-string argument, this argument is returned unchanged. So your function returns the event object in `jsStr` unchanged.

Now, some event handlers support return value (like if you return `false` from a click handler of an `<a>` element, the link is not followed). However, according to

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch19_01.htm

`onload` handler does not modify its behaviour based on the return value. Therefore, this code ultimately does nothing.

Of course, everyone suspected that, but I wanted to enlighten you on whether `jsStr` could be defined.

Answer (score 0):

I believe MM_callJS is a Dreamweaver behavior code snippet.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. I stumbled across the use of `MM_callJS` in the source of a website and was wondering what sane developer would use such a pattern. It does appear to be code generated by Dreamweaver.